# Is there a way to pass the value of a dictionary pair into a variable in C#?

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm new to C#. I tried to store the value of a dictionary pair in a variable based on if an IF statement evaluates to True, but it's not behaving as I would expect it to. I'm trying to get creative with a project I'm working on and would like to learn how to use dictionaries in this way.

```
string newFileName = "EOYReportPRF.xls";
string dirInfo_Source = "C:\Temp\"

Dictionary<string, string> fileNameChanges = new Dictionary<string, string>();
fileNameChanges.Add("EOYReportPRF.xls", "EOY_PRF.xls");
fileNameChanges.Add("PayrollEOY.xls", "EOY_SU.xls");
fileNameChanges.Add("PRFFundingStatement.xls", "FS_PRF.xls");
fileNameChanges.Add("SUFundingStatement.xls", "FS_SU.xls");

if (fileNameChanges.ContainsKey(newFileName))
    {
    File.Move(dirInfo_Source + newFileName, dirInfo_Source + fileNameChanges.Values.ToString());
    }
```

I know that the code is incorrect. I'm just trying to get this to work properly. I want to loop through a directory, passing the name of each file into the newFileName variable. If newFileName matches a key in the dictionary, such as "EOYReportPRF.xls", then I'd like to use the value of the dictionary pair as the file name. Need some help thinking through this. Thanks!

Comment: You never get the value from the dictionary, you just check if the key exists.

Comment: As @Ben is implying, after identifying that the `key` exists, you can retrieve it with `fileNameChanges[newFileName]`

Comment: Why the [tag:ssis] tag?

Comment: I tagged c# first. I'm developing a script task in SSIS using C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the actual value for the key:

```
        string newFileName = "EOYReportPRF.xls";
        string dirInfo_Source = @"C:\Temp\";

        Dictionary<string, string> fileNameChanges = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        fileNameChanges.Add("EOYReportPRF.xls", "EOY_PRF.xls");
        fileNameChanges.Add("PayrollEOY.xls", "EOY_SU.xls");
        fileNameChanges.Add("PRFFundingStatement.xls", "FS_PRF.xls");
        fileNameChanges.Add("SUFundingStatement.xls", "FS_SU.xls");

        if (fileNameChanges.ContainsKey(newFileName))
        {
            var filename = fileNameChanges[newFileName];
            File.Move(dirInfo_Source + newFileName, dirInfo_Source + filename);
        }
```

That should work.

Comment: Well, it did! I've been scratching my head for hours trying to figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: Please use `TryGetValue` rather than `ContainsKey`.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using TryGetValue method.

```
 string val;
 string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(dirInfo_Source);

    foreach(string fileName in fileEntries){
        if(fileNameChanges.TryGetValue(fileName, out val)){
               File.Move(dirInfo_Source + fileName , dirInfo_Source + val);   
       }

 }
```